# Selenium Webdriver Stuck while selecting Date and Time

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying test a website using Selenium. Selenium is often being stopped at selecting Time picker and Date picker. Even I tried with some sleep time, it didn't work.

Here is the code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("DeparturePoint")).sendKeys("New York");
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalPoint")).sendKeys("Paris");
driver.findElement(By.id("DepartureTime")).sendKeys("12:01 am");   
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalTime")).sendKeys("12:01 am");
Thread.sleep(1000); 
driver.findElement(By.id("DepartureDate")).sendKeys("07/10/2016");  
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalDate")).sendKeys("07/16/2016");
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Here is a screenshot of the page being tested:

[image]

Comment: can you please provide us with the exact exception you get?

Comment: Sure. Selenium unable to click on 'Add' button beneath Date picker.

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (849, 326). Other element would receive the click: <th scope="col">...</th>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Never Mind Folks.
[This link ][1] helps me to resolve the issue. Just added line to focus on next element **driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalTime")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);**

**The Update Code:**

driver.findElement(By.id("DeparturePoint")).sendKeys("New York");
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalPoint")).sendKeys("Paris");
driver.findElement(By.id("DepartureTime")).sendKeys("12:01 am");   
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalTime")).sendKeys("12:01 am");
Thread.sleep(1000); 
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalTime")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.findElement(By.id("DepartureDate")).sendKeys("07/10/2016");  
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalDate")).sendKeys("07/16/2016");
Thread.sleep(1000); 
driver.findElement(By.id("ArrivalTime")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
  [1]: http://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you need to click into each control to give it focus away from the pickers, THEN you can send keys.  This assumes that these controls actually let you type characters into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

The Button you want to click is blocked. Selenium can only click on elements that are visible and not covered by another element.

You could e.g. click on another element to close the date pcikers (or into the layer itsself depending on the website)

```
driver.findElement(By.id("DeparturePoint")).click();
```

After that the Button should be visible again